# Which one of the following macros is safe and why?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

For getting maximum of two numbers i have following macros

```
#define max(a,b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))

#define maxint(a,b) ({int _a = (a), _b = (b); _a > _b ? _a : _b; })
```

What is the difference between above both. which one is better to use and why.
I found these macros' information [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs). But unable to understand it.

Comment: Think about what is generated by the preprocessor with `max(++i, --j)`. And *neither* is "safe", but the latter isn't as prone to side-effects related to macro parameter expansion.

Comment: Second is safer. e.g. call `max(i++,j++)` Or for that matter, `max(fn1(),fn2())`

Comment: Note that the second of these macros uses a `gcc` extension (treating a block statement as an expression) and therefore isn't portable.

Comment: See the reference you provided " #define max(a,b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
But this definition computes either a or b twice, with bad results if the operand has side effects."

Comment: Use the first version but name it `MAX(a,b)`. This naming convention warns the user to be careful when using it, in particular not to do something like `MAX(a++, b++)` when using the macro.

Comment: @Chinna, consider dropping the 'linux' tag?

Comment: What is the compelling benefit of either macro? Why not simply define a function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second macro is safer, but uses a non-standard C extension provided by GCC : [statement expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html). But the first expression is "generic". Using the [typeof](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) extension of GCC would help:

```
 #define mymax(a,b) ({typeof(a) _a = (a); typeof(b) _b = (b); \
                      _a > _b ? _a : _b; })
```

To fight against the issue raised in [JaredPar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21300971/841108) you could use preprocessor [concatenation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html) and GCC specific [`__COUNTER__`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) (or just the more standard `__LINE__`), e.g.

```
 #define mymax_counted(a,b,c) ({typeof(a) _a##c = (a); \
                                typeof(b) _b##c = (b); \
                                _a##c > _b##c ? _a##c : _b##c; })
 #define mymax(a,b) mymax_counted(a,b,__COUNTER__)
```

but even that is not entirely fail-proof (with bad luck; could collide in some invocation like `mymax(_a123,_b123)` if the unique `__COUNTER__` happens to be 123 at that time).

Actually, using an [inline function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function) is better (because if you call `mymaxfun(i++,t[i])` the behavior is well defined and gives the same result as `mymaxfun(t[i],i++)`, and because optimizing compilers would produce code as efficient as when using a macro):

```
static inline int mymaxfun(int a, int b) { return (a>b)?a:b; }
```

Sadly, C don't have generic functions (consider for that switching to [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) with its [templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_%28C++%29) and use [std::max](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/)); however [C11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) has type-generic expressions using the `_Generic` keyword

Macros are useful (when mastered), but you should be very careful about side effects in arguments when calling macros (e.g. `mymax(i++,t[--i]++)`) so you always should care and *document* if a name is a macro or something else (like a function). As a rule of thumb avoid side-effects -notably `++` or `--` but also many others- in function-call looking expressions (both function calls and macro invocations).

Look at the preprocessor-expanded form of your source code; so for a `foo.c` source code, run `gcc -C -E foo.c > foo.i` (adding whatever preprocessor options like `-I`, `-D` etc... are relevant) and look inside `foo.i` e.g. with `less foo.i`; it is always instructive.

Comment: The only problem being when someone tries to use it with floats.

Answer (score 6):

The second macro is safer because it evaluates the inputs exactly once.  This is important if the inputs are expressions that have side effects for example

```
max(i++, --j);
```

Note that i said safer and not safe.  It's still possible for this macro to be incorrect because there could be locals in scope which are already named `_a` and `_`b.  Imagine what would happen if the following was executed

```
int _a = 42;
int _b = 13;
maxint(_a, _b);
```

It would expand out to

```
int _a = 42;
int _b = 13;
{int _a = (_a), _b = (_b); _a > _b ? _a : _b; })
```

Comment: Good point, though I note that it is an *extremely* poor programming practice to begin a local variable with an underscore, for this exact reason.

Answer (score 2):

**Neither are safe**. Please avoid flashy `max` macro implementations that rely on non-standard C extensions like *expression statements* which will give you all sort of headaches if you ever have to port your code to a different platform. Doing my best to present this answer from becoming a rant, the `max` macro is, in my opinion, one of the worst things in C standard libraries due to its potential side-effects. In times past, I've #`undef`ed `max` just to be on the safe side.

Your're better off coding the second macro `maxint` as a function as it has all the drawbacks of macros (e.g. can't debug easily, instantiated variables clashing with locals) but none of the benefits (e.g. genericisation).

**Alternatives**:

My favourite: use the ternary inline: `a > b ? a : b` where you can drop the parentheses to taste since you know exactly what is going on. It will also be faster than macros that try to be safe by taking value copies.

Build your own functions. Consider defining `max` for integral types and `fmax` for floating point. There is already a precedent here with `abs` and `fabs`.

Comment: The ternary inline is not a good alternative if you assume that OPs problem is likely not literally the max-function but a more complicated expression.